# Not allowed to use internet in France?

Tags: hardware, pi-3b+, commercial-use

According to the [Declaration of Conformity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/compliance/rpi_DOC_3bplus_EU_RED.pdf), only indoor use is permitted. Is this just regarding the WiFi, or the whole Pi? What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Looks to me you're confusing 'indoor' with 'home' use (based on the tags you have chosen), And as such it has nothing to do with commercial use or Internet access

Comment: @Dirk maybe I should update the tags as I know commercial use has little to do with it and Internet access can be achieved via a Ethernet, for example. Still, the document reads "The WLAN radio technology of this device is designed for use in all countires ... In France indoor use only is permitted." Does that not mean that WLAN, or wireless, can not be used outdoors? The "indoor use only is permitted" is relating to the WiFi system (be it the antenna, chip, or whatever) no?

Comment: "Indoor use" means you can't use any wireless radio on your RPi in your back garden, in your car or hand-held in the street. I suggest you get in touch with your local MEP to get that stupidity changed.

Comment: I doubt they can really do something about it, if you use it in your garden...

Answer (score -1):

Pi can be used as a transmitter or a controller with correct equipment. This is the main reason.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand your answer. What has it to do with the Declaration of Conformity?